# CONVERTING DATA VARCHAR TO NUMERIC

Tags: sql-server, decimal, percentage, numeric, varchar

Example data:

```
12.12%,
6,
1,
10%,
8.347%,
16.27
```

Code

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(10,3), [Discount]) AS [Discount]
FROM [RDMS_DEV].[dbo].[t_TNSDiscount_dtl]
```

Error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Expected Results:

```
12.12%,
6%,
1%,
10%,
8.347%,
16.27%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your data because having '%' character for the solution remove it by having replace function.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255),REPLACE([Discount], '%', '')) + '%' AS [Discount] 
FROM [RDMS_DEV].[dbo].[t_TNSDiscount_dtl]
```

You can use also add CONVERT(decimal(10,3), [Discount]) to force in 3 decimal places.

> New answer as the question changed: So for the update every time the data is greater and equal to 10, I concatenate '%' symbol.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(decimal,REPLACE([Discount], '%', '')) <  10 THEN CONVERT(varchar(255),REPLACE([Discount], '%', '')) ELSE
CONVERT(varchar(255),REPLACE([Discount], '%', ''))   + '%' END AS [Discount] 
FROM [RDMS_DEV].[dbo].[t_TNSDiscount_dtl]
```

> Output result for updated question:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it's really appriciated

Comment: @Lydia no worries, just keep on coding! let me know if you have more questions :)

Comment: hey, anyway I just got an update today, turns out not all he data need to be in %, ca you help me?

Comment: @Lydia yes I can help you, so not all should have '%', for every single digit should not have % sign? I am right?

Comment: yup, I just need some of them, because apparently they also insert how much money they want to disc. If I insert the prev query the amount of money also got "%" too.

Comment: @Lydia based on my understanding on your expected output., I Updated my answer, Let me know if this kind query helps you.

Comment: that's still not it, I've tried it, and somehow the one that originally have "%" on it is now just plain numbers, also some large number still receive "%". I'm currently also trying o tweak it. Please help. Thanks n advance ^^

Comment: I think I get it, you just need to change you "<" to ">" and "10" to "100" since it is impossible for a product to be disc until 100%. I can't thank you enough. You are a life saver ^^

Comment: You can retract your flags if you no longer need them @justinmontalban

Comment: @YvetteColomb how?

Comment: @justinmontalban go to the post you flagged  and there will be an option to retract the flag. Once it's  been handled by a mod it's too late to retract it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: You need to remove the '%' from the discount value.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    Id INT ,
    Discount VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Discount)VALUES(1, '12.12%')
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Discount)VALUES(1, '6')
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Discount)VALUES(1, '1')
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Discount)VALUES(1, '10%')
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Discount)VALUES(1, '8.347%')
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Discount)VALUES(1, '16.27')


SELECT CONVERT(decimal(10,3), REPLACE([Discount],'%','')) AS [Discount] FROM @tbl
```